# Magento 2 change store view

Tags: redirect, store-view, magento2.1.6

> I'm trying this script to detect browser language and redirect to
>   Italian store view if the language is Italian or English store view if
>   the language is not Italian. The country code is correctly detected
>   but I'm not able to redirect to the store view. I've also tried using
>   header('Location: ' . $lang), lang was 'Italian' or 'default'. It
>   works but I don't want to have in the URL the store view code.
>
> Here is the script:

```
function getCountryCode(){
  $CountryCode = substr(getenv('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);
  if ($CountryCode=='it') {
    $lang = 3;
  }
  else{ 
    $lang = 1;
 }

 return $lang;
}

$lang = getCountryCode();

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

$objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')-
>setCurrentStore(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change store in magento 2 you need to change store code and website in index.php file

Here is some information about store view and website

Each website and each store view must have a unique identifier. This identifier is required to use MAGE_RUN_TYPE and MAGE_RUN_CODE as follows:

MAGE_RUN_TYPE can be either store or website

Use website to load a website in your storefront.
Use store to load any store view in your storefront.
MAGE_RUN_CODE is the unique website or store view code that corresponds to MAGE_RUN_TYPE

First you need to find out store code by current language using HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE or by using customer's IP

To change store you need to set store code while creating bootstrap object

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); 


$params = $_SERVER;

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $store; // add store code here

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $website;
```

Comment: So, if I'm trying to switch store views I should use 'store' for PARAM_RUN_TYPE ?

Comment: No if you want to change stores you have to set store code in PARAM_RUN_CODE

Answer (score -1):

Please comment below code in **index.php**

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**And then add below code**

```
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

    switch ($lang) {
        case "it":
            $params = $_SERVER; $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '<YOUR_ITALIAN_STORE_CODE_HERE>'; 
            $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
            $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
            $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
            $bootstrap->run($app); 
            break;     
        default: 
            $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
            $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
            $bootstrap->run($app);
        break; 
    }
```

Make sure you took backup your original **index.php** file.

Comment: Thank you for the  help, but I've tried it and it gives error: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity

Comment: I've found a solution, it is store and not website because i'm trying to switch store views